# Why am I getting dropped from multiplayer to main menu?

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4

Having been a long time player of Diablo 3 on PC, I bought the game on PS4 a few days ago for some sofa gaming.

My friend invited me to his game, so I created a character and joined the party. I could see thier characters in the lobby, so I hit 'Enter game' loaded for a few seconds, and then appeared in game. I could run around as normal, but then I was immediatly back at the main menu. Strange I thought, I didn't get an error or anything.

I tried again, and roughly 30 seconds after joining the game, I find myself back at the main menu. Tried a number more times, and had the same issue.

I tried hosting a game and had my friends join that one, which did actually work just fine.

I've spent some time trying to find out what this issue might be, but most of the forum posts are very old, or on the wrong platform. My first assumption is that the PS4 version, uses different ports, which might need to be forwarded from my router. I don't, however, know these ports.

So my question is multifaceted, how can I fix this disconnection issue, and what multiplayer ports does Diablo 3 on PS4 use? If indeed the ports are at all relevant.

Comment: It's worth noting that I no longer have this issue. It resolved itself shortly afterwards.